# Elastic lists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, elasticlayout

I recently came across  [Elastic Lists](http://well-formed-data.net/experiments/elastic_lists/) & found them totally cool.

Is anyone aware of a javascript library which can give me elastic lists ? 
If not , any tips on writing it myself too would be most welcomed. :)

Thanks,

Comment: Wow, what a great program (+1). I could probably make something like it, but school is starting for me soon so it might take some time.

Answer (score 1):

+1 on Elastic Lists. I've played around with their ilk in some Adobe Flex applications and they are a lot of fun and very powerful.  I don't know of any JavaScript / HTML libraries already written for generating them, but I feel like you could adapt some of the controls and behaviors in the [JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) Library into an Elastic List type control.  I can offer an additional [link to some nice usability studies](http://flamenco.berkeley.edu/pubs.html) on Elastic Lists and multi-faceted search/navigation, hopefully that will help you along if you end up creating your own interface.  Best of luck, and if you end up writing it yourself, open source it on GitHub or someplace similar, I'd be interested in contributing.

**EDIT:**

I just remembered that in addition to the usability studies there is some [open source code](http://flamenco.berkeley.edu/download.html) on that site as well that is used in that Nobel Prize winners demo that you linked to, as well as some several other [examples of elastic lists](http://flamenco.berkeley.edu/demos.html).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful link- few days back I too was looking for search user interfaces & this is really useful. :)
As far as writing the library is concerned- I am not much of a Java script pro really. But still if I write something I ll definitely open source it & let you know!

Answer (score 0):

One implementation of elastic lists in javascript can be found on github. It uses protovis, the predecessor of d3js. -- https://github.com/esjewett/protovis_elastic_lists